# Передача произвольного числа параметров в конструктор и дальнейшая их передача другому конструктору

Tags: php

Вот как сделать такой вот функционал?

```
public function __construct($type='file',куча параметров) {
    if($type=='file') {
        return new Class(куча параметров);
    }
}
```

куча параметров должна передаться в новый создаваемый класс, причем параметров может и не быть

А первый параметр передаваемый в главный конструктор должен отпасть

Кстати обратите внимание на первый параметр `$type='file'`, который по умолчанию - это я к тому что функция `func_get_args` работать не будет, потому что его не увидит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Не благодари](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: С сайта 
Замечание: Эта функция возвращает только копии переданных аргументов, и не возвращает значения по умолчанию (непереданных) аргументов.

Comment: именно то что вам надо